# Can I raise a number to the power of a vector in R?

Tags: r, pow

I have a vector and want to raise a number to the power of the vector's elements without using a loop. Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried a^b where a is a number and b is a vector but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: r <- 3; power <- 1:3; r^power # 3  9 27

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that "doesn't work" for you? What exactly did you try? You shouldn't need a loop. The exponent operator is vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponentiation operation must be carefully performed in R, since a negative base can give wrong results.

**Wrong**

```
power <- function(x, y) x^y

power(2, 3)
#[1] 8
power(2, -3)
#[1] 0.125

power(1, 1/3)
#[1] 1
power(-1, 1/3)
#[1] NaN
```

**Right**

```
power <- function(x, y) sign(x) * abs(x)^y

power(2, 3)
#[1] 8
power(2, -3)
#[1] 0.125
power(1, 1/3)
#[1] 1
power(-1, 1/3)
#[1] -1
```

Now see if this second `power` function is vectorized, like the question asks for.

```
power(2, c(1:4, pi, -pi, -1/3, 1/3))
#[1]  2.0000000  4.0000000  8.0000000 16.0000000  8.8249778  0.1133147
#[7]  0.7937005  1.2599210

outer(c(-2, 2), c(1:4, pi, -pi, -1/3, 1/3), power)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]
#[1,]   -2   -4   -8  -16 -8.824978 -0.1133147 -0.7937005 -1.259921
#[2,]    2    4    8   16  8.824978  0.1133147  0.7937005  1.259921
```